# python 2.7 django 1.6 how to set my application on a free server

Tags: django

I am new on hosting servers and i want to know the easiest way to get my django app running on a free/or not hosting server.

Please give some very detail information's and suggestions!!!

My application is built on python 2.7 with Django 1.6

Comment: Commenting this just follow this questions,

Answer (score 0):

Follow this documentation   :

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django